# Why does Xubuntu boot splash image take longer to appear than before?

Tags: boot, grub2, updates

**Since upgrading from Xubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 on a Lenovo S21e notebook, the screen stays black (after GRUB) for quite a while, until the first boot splash screen is shown.**
(Always makes me a bit nervous, since it seems like the computer is dead/frozen).

**The black screen lasts around 30 seconds.**
This was *not so* in previous versions of Xubuntu.

Maybe a duplicate of question #271898, but I couldn't find a solution there:
[What is GRUB doing while it takes 9 minutes to start booting the kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271898/what-is-grub-doing-while-it-takes-9-minutes-to-start-booting-the-kernel?rq=1)

I've lived with this for a year now, but yesterday same happened on a Thinkpad Edge E335 (12.04 to 18.04), so I thought I'd finally ask for help :(

Is anyone else experiencing this?
Does anyone know which action in the boot process might be causing this (and how to fix it)?

I've checked dmesg, /var/log/*, etc but couldn't find anything suspicious. When checking runtimes of boot processes, their sums were less than the black screen timeout. So it seems like the black screen happens before the boot logs begin.

Feels like a hardware-probing-but-fail timeout, but that's just a gut feeling.

**Grateful for any hints :)
Thanks in advance!**

PS: I'm using (X|K)Ubuntu since 6.06, so you can send me to commandline :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04LTS I use the following command  to "prints an SVG graphic detailing which system services have been started at what time, highlighting the time they spent on initialization":   systemd-analyze plot > boot_analysis.svg

Comment: Thanks TonyB.

But the graph only shows "Kernel+afterwards" - and this issue seems to be before the Kernel is even loaded...